How to parse and print API response and Error code from pymeter in python script?
How to parse and print API response and Error code from pymeter in python script?
PyMeter is python version of jmeter.
(pymeter help document - https://pymeter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)
I am trying to get the performance stats for API - https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 and it gives following response. I am able to execute api using pymeter sampler, however unable to find any help doc about how to parse API response.
{"page":2,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":7,"email":"michael.lawson@reqres.in","first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Lawson","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"},{"id":8,"email":"lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in","first_name":"Lindsay","last_name":"Ferguson","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"},{"id":9,"email":"tobias.funke@reqres.in","first_name":"Tobias","last_name":"Funke","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"},{"id":10,"email":"byron.fields@reqres.in","first_name":"Byron","last_name":"Fields","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"},{"id":11,"email":"george.edwards@reqres.in","first_name":"George","last_name":"Edwards","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"},{"id":12,"email":"rachel.howell@reqres.in","first_name":"Rachel","last_name":"Howell","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"}],"support":{"url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}

Here is my sample script -
from unittest import TestCase
from pymeter.api.config import TestPlan, ThreadGroupWithRampUpAndHold
from pymeter.api.samplers import HttpSampler
from pymeter.api.reporters import HtmlReporter
from pymeter.api.postprocessors import JsonExtractor
from pymeter.api.assertions import ResponseAssertion

class TestTestPlanClass(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(TestTestPlanClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      print("TestTestPlanClass")

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("setUpClass")

    def test_case_1(self):
        json_extractor = JsonExtractor("variable", "args.data")

        # create HTTP sampler, sends a get request to the given url
        ra = ResponseAssertion().contains_substrings("data")
        http_sampler = HttpSampler("echo_get_request", "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", json_extractor)

        # create html reporter
        html_reporter = HtmlReporter()

        # create a thread group that will rump up 10 threads in 1 second and
        # hold the load for additional 10 seconds, give it the http sampler as a child input
        thread_group_main = ThreadGroupWithRampUpAndHold(1, 1, 1, http_sampler)

        # create a test plan with the required thread group
        test_plan = TestPlan(thread_group_main, html_reporter)

        # run the test plan and take the results
        stats = test_plan.run()

        self.assertLess(stats.sample_time_99_percentile_milliseconds, 2000)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("tearDownClass")
 


Looking into pymeter source code I cannot see anything suitable class you could use, if you want to continue with pymeter you will need to develop the functionality yourself.
Instead of Python you can consider using JMeter Java DSL.
It's also possible to build and run a JMeter test plan programmatically using Java or Kotlin languages
